# Facebook marketing API custom website audience targeting using API

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook **marketing API v2.8** (**JAVA** preferred)

I am trying to creating `custom website audiences` using Facebook pixel by using the below rule :

**String rule** = `"{\"url\":{\"eq\":\"http://www.example.com/abc.php\"}}"`

```
public static CustomAudience createWebsitePixelCustomAudience(AdAccount adAccount, String pixelId, 
            String audienceName, EnumSubtype subtype, String rule) throws 

    APIException {
            CustomAudience customAudience = adAccount.createCustomAudience()
                      .setPixelId(pixelId)
                      .setName(audienceName)
                      .setSubtype(CustomAudience.EnumSubtype.VALUE_WEBSITE)
                      .setRetentionDays(15L)
                      .setRule(rule)
                      .setPrefill(true)
                      .execute();
            return customAudience;
        }
```

**What I want to achieve?**

I want to target these audiences created above **using API** (**Java** preferred).

**I tried to do this using this below code by passing Id** of `custom audiences` created above.

```
public static Targeting targetAudience(List<String> countrylist, String customAudienceID) {

        TargetingGeoLocation geoLocation = new TargetingGeoLocation()
                .setFieldCountries(countrylist);

        Targeting targeting = new Targeting()
                .setFieldGeoLocations(geoLocation)
                .setFieldCustomAudiences(customAudienceID);
        return targeting;
    }
```

I used the `customAudienceID` that I created at the start and passed it to above function.

**But I am getting this error** : `Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was NUMBER at line 1 column 14 path`

**Is this the correct way of linking** `custom website audience` to `AdSet`?
Thanks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally I find a way to do it :**

```
public static Targeting targetCustomAudience(List<String> countrylist, String customAudienceID) {

        TargetingGeoLocation geoLocation = new TargetingGeoLocation()
                .setFieldCountries(countrylist);
        /**
         * add geo-location to targeting
         * add custom audienceId to targeting
         */
        Targeting targeting = new Targeting()
                .setFieldGeoLocations(geoLocation)
                .setFieldCustomAudiences("[{id:" + customAudienceID + "}]");
        return targeting;
    }
```

Thanks to [this link](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-java-ads-sdk/blob/master/examples/CustomAudienceExample.java)

In short add this line `"[{id:" + customAudienceID + "}]"` to add custom audience to targeting.